# Google books dynamic pages

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if it is possible to do something like [this](http://books.google.com/ebooks/reader?id=2Zc3AAAAYAAJ&hl=it&printsec=frontcover&output=reader&source=webstore_bookcard&pg=GBS.PA168.w.1.3.0) using Javascript.
I think that's a very difficult thing to implement (just try resizing the window), and I don't know if there is something on the web (I did not find anything though).

Comment: The example is written in Javascript so yes, absolutely, it is possible in Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simple, if you're able to pass text of whole book to page.

Simple todo-list (MVC)

- PHP: get book from db and pass its content to `view`
- Create four DIVs

  - first to `previous page action`
  - second to `left page`
  - third to `right page`
  - fourth to `next page action`

these DIVs are 100% height of browser window and their width is:

- 30px
- (page.width-60)/2
- (page.width-60)/2
- 30px

and via Javascript you will just split up the book's text to so many pages via counting words (for example `one page == 200 words`)

and if the page is not so high to take all text, let's scroll vertically like they do on given example

more functions they implement are:

- search (see javascript string.search() )
- resizing font (see javascript css methods or read [Javascript Change Font Size](http://ilovethecode.com/Javascript/Javascript-Tutorials/Javascript_Change_Font_Size.shtml) )
- walking book by chapters ( depends on your implementation *1 )
- bottom slider (again depends on your implementation, but jquery slider is quite usable for this one)

***1**

- you can simply pass your book's text to your view in array by chapters
- you can pass only chapters and let fetch chapters text via AJAX call
- or whatever you can think of ...

About ready implementations, you can see these:

- http://michaelthompson.org/books/read.php?book=b5
- http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/gerv/archives/2006/05/amazon_ajax_book_reader.html (like page images - scans -  implementation)
- http://openlibrary.org/dev/docs/bookreader
- http://monocle.inventivelabs.com.au/ ( again scanned pages like images of final size )

Comment: I'm sorry about the bounty. I was sure yours was the accepted answer, but I was still thinking about the bounty. Anyway, you deserve it. Thank you

Comment: I don't blame you for anything :) I'm happy my answer helped you to clear out the situation

Comment: @MassimoFazzolari sorry for the simplification, I know it's not easy task, but I've tried to help as much as I could at the time. If you have more complete answer, feel free to post it.